# Excel-vba Create new sheet on click with a name from a specific cel

Tags: vba, excel

Basically I need code to create a new worksheet when the user clicks on one column and than sets the name from a different column as the file name.

Right now I have 3 columns: Projects, Status and Filename. So what I mean is that if the user clicks on a cell in the Projects column it will create a sheet from a template I made inside the same file. And the file name will be the same as the cell from the 'filename' column in the same row.

EDIT: If the sheet already exists I would like to open it the existing file instead

Comment: A sheet or a file? And what if the user clicks the column several times? Create a new sheet or file each time? What about the existing sheets / files? Overwrite? Add new? I think you need to spend some more time on defining the logic. Oh, and what have you tried? Your post cut off.

Comment: Yes I was actually at school and someone posted it while I wasn't paying attention :/ I updated the post

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
      Sub CreateNewSheet()
    Dim selectedcell As Range
    Set selectedcell = Selection
    If selectedcell Is Nothing Or selectedcell.Value = "" Or selectedcell.Offset(0, 2) = "" Then
    MsgBox ("Error: Cell not selected or project row is empty")
    Exit Sub
    Else
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    For Each ws In Sheets
    lw = ws.Name
    Next
    Worksheets(lw).Name = selectedcell.Offset(0, 2).Value
    End If
End Sub
```

ouput:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be just to create Hyperlink.

Add Hyperlink -> Create New Document

Supported by Events will create new Workbook and run macro.

```
Private Sub Workbook_WindowDeactivate(ByVal Wn As Window)
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).value = "I am working"
End Sub
```

Comment: Pardon, you were asking about Worksheet, not Workbook, sorry. I was misled by "file name" you mentioned in the question.